# Is there any way to log entered password from ssh?

Tags: ssh, logging, password, login, ssh-tunnel

My server is under attack and some one try to run brute force attack on my ssh port, I know that I can block the IPs which are illegal,with iptables,fail2ban, ... but I want to know which password attacker try on my ssh, is there any way to log the attempted password on ssh?

Answer (score 6):

You can visualize the failed user names after you turn up the verbosity of the log in `sshd_config`¹, but there is no way to see the failed passwords as this could be a potential security issue and would violates the privacy of users (for example you could mistype your password and it would be leaked into some log file).

All the passwords are handled as extremely sensitive data and only stored in memory and never written to a log so they will not be able to leak out of their security context.

To do this, you should use some specially crafted honey-pot custom-made for this use case, not standard production security products.

¹ See `man sshd_config` for more information

<sup>From my original answer on [unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/235216/121504)</sup>